# Dimensions of Standoffs and Screws for ATX Motherboard

Tags: motherboard, atx, screws, case-mods

What are the dimensions for the **standoffs** and **screws** used for mounting an ATX motherboard to the computer casing? I'm using them to make my own motherboard mounting plate.

Some sources say the standoffs are 6-32 to 6-32 for the threads, some say its 6-32 to M3. However on Grainger/Mcmaster I cant find any M3 tapped standoffs with #6-32 threads, its either 6-32 to 6-32 or M3 to M3.

I bought some [6-32-1/2L male-female hex standoffs from Grainger](https://www.mcmaster.com/#standard-threaded-standoffs/=19vr3do) but they look odd.

In [Mcmaster](https://www.mcmaster.com/#standard-threaded-standoffs/=19vr3do) I narrowed down to these Male-Female Threaded Hex Standoffs which are

- Brass
- 6-32 thread size
- 1/4" length

Which should I get?

[image]

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (hardware shopping). Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask). Try [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).  but please first read [What is required for a question to be 'high quality'?"](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-be-high-quality).

Comment: Motherboard manufacturers and case manufacturers are a better source for answering this question.  If you find the answer, even by trial-and-error, please answer your own question so that the next person who has the same question can benefit.

Comment: @DavidPostill I am asking people who have had the same problem for which sizes of screw and standoffs that can be used for attaching ATX motherboards to computer cases. Hardware Recommendations appear to be for shopping for consumer electronics. Please recommend a more suitable place than this, thanks

Comment: @DavidPostill This question is not asking for a recommendation of which hardware to buy or where to buy them. It is asking, *in general terms*, what the standard sizes are. Also, why did you state that the question is off-topic and then answer it?

Answer (score 6):

#### What are the dimensions for the standoffs and screws used for mounting an ATX motherboard to the computer casing?

It depends.

According to the [ATX 2.1 standard](http://www.formfactors.org/developer/specs/atx2_1.pdf):

- The standoff provided has to be a minimum of 6.5mm and the external cross section has to fit within a 10mm x 10mm area around the standoff hole.
- The mounting screws must (obviously) match the standoff screw wells (usually 6/32 or M3 thread size).
- the length can be whatever you want as long as the components will fit in your case. A longer standoff allows cables to be run under the motherboard and may also improve airflow.

---

> According to the [ATX 2.1 standard](http://www.formfactors.org/developer/specs/atx2_1.pdf), the standoff provided has to be a minimum of 6.5mm and the external cross section has to fit within a 10mm x 10mm area around the standoff hole.
>
> There's a lot of variation (as you've discovered) to how various manufacturers meet those specs, but as long as the mounting screws match the standoff screw wells (usually 6/32 or M3 thread size) it doesn't really matter what the external width is as long as it's within the 10mm x 10mm max size requirement.

Source [Motherboard standoff dimensions](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2449956/motherboard-standoff-dimensions.html)

---

> From experience over many years, they are all standard threads and
> size, but not length, that varies by case manufacturer.
>
> Generally a computer case will come with 9 standoffs to meet ATX
> standards, unless the case is smaller. The majority of ATX
> motherboards will use 6, smaller boards even less. More expensive
> 'wider' ATX boards will use all 9, which is nice when they are right
> next to the main I/O for the disk drives.
>
> There are many cases available that use zero or only some standoffs
> and use threaded and stamped raised sheet metal for the stand offs.

---

Source [Motherboard Standoffs Sizes](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2251173/motherboard-standoffs-sizes.html)

> You can buy a standoff anywhere between 4mm to 10mm in length as far as I know. I have standoffs measuring 4mm, 6mm, 7mm and 8mm.
>
> Personally I like a larger standoff to allow cable routing behind the motherboard. Thin cables obviously. It also allows a better airflow behind the motherboard in my opinion.

Source [Motherboard Standoff Heights?](http://www.overclock.net/t/276408/motherboard-standoff-heights)

Comment: In other words, the thread will either depend on the case, if one exists, or otherwise it just needs to match between the screws and the socket. They just provide clamping force for the motherboard but the exact thread can differ between cases (that provide matching screws and standoffs in the package).

Answer (score 1):

So after a lot of deliberation here's what essentially going to boil down to opinion, but at least maybe it'll answer your question.

The bore depth on the plate can vary as much as you like, however as your image shows, the thread size is a standard which you should match.

You can get ATX standoffs in a huge assortment of sizes and shapes as well as materials (by sizes I mean the length of the thread as well as the 'nut' can vary how ever the width).

As long as your motherboard + any expansion cards which are sitting perpendicular to it fit within your case, you can have *any* sized stand offs you like (they obviously need to be big enough to stand off from the back plate, and for some cpus they'll require a little room for holding plates which fit to the back side of the cpu - this varies too much to easily answer, check for the specific CPU model you want).

You may want longer stand offs if you want to run cabling between the motherboard and the back plate, especially if you're using a case which doesn't have much room behind the back plate for cable management.

Answer (score 0):

I've owned many PC cases from various leading brands headquartered in various parts of the world.

All those cases came with motherboards standoffs that are ASME/ANSI B1.1 UNC #6, 32 threads per inch (a.k.a. 6-32), on both the male end that fits into the case and the female end for the motherboard screws. The body of the standoffs were all 3/16 inch hex.

The lenght (or height, if you will) of the hex part varies, but most measured 6.50 to 6.70mm, with a 4mm minimum length male thread typically.

This is what you could call anecdotal evidence, but based on my experience I'm pretty confident that's what the "unofficial standard" is.