# How theoretically low can a motherboard be to the ground

Tags: motherboard, desktop-customization, case

Everytime i see a computer case with a screwed in motherboard. I notice there is a decent amount of gap in between the ground and where the mother board sits. Theoretically, how low can the bottom of your motherboard be to the groud (in mm). Can you safely mount it to the ground?

Comment: “Can you safely mount it to the ground?” – If you could, there would be no need for this. ;) PC cases are typically metal. A circuit board touching it could result in short-circuits.

Comment: The answer depends in part on the height of any objects protruding past the bottom of the motherboard silicon. Therefore we need to know exactly what motherboard you have in mind.

Comment: It depends on how long the legs are on the back of the components mounted onto the motherboard, and what insulation there is (if any) between the motherboard and 'the ground'. Look at 'motherboard spacer', most are 11mm long. If you want to adhere to ATX standards, according to the ATX 2.1 standard: The standoff provided has to be a minimum of 6.5mm and the external cross section has to fit within a 10mm x 10mm area around the standoff hole.

Comment: Also see https://superuser.com/questions/1260592/dimensions-of-standoffs-and-screws-for-atx-motherboard

Comment: I've totally run a motherboard on a desk or a MDF board with no standoffs (there's even a term for this - bench testing.). If you didn't particularly care about pesky things like good airflow and mechanical support being engineered for a specific set of mount points, I suppose you could just stick the motherboard to a flat surface with something like 3M VHB.

Answer (score 0):

Most motherboards are attached to their case or sone other metal plate using standoff screws . Similar to the ones below.

The standoffs prevent the electrical components on the bottom of the motherboard from touching the metal of the case. If the metal contacts on the underside of the motherboard touched the case while it was powered on, bit could result in the computer not working at best, or destroy it at worst. A higher voltage rail could pass through a lower voltage circuit and burn out the components.

As far as I know, there is no minimum height. You want enough distance to keep the board from flexing into the case if it wasn't properly supported and heavy components are I stalled on it. Additionally, you do t want it so low an electrical arc could jump from the board to the case.

[image]

Comment: What if I made my case out of something that wasnt conductive like plastic?

Comment: Then you would not need any clearancr and the motherboard could sit on the case.